# Android switch: how to disable response to touch event?

Tags: android, user-interface

So i'm developing an Android application and I've added some switch to indicate the status of some elements.

But the problme is I hope to control the status by a thread, instread of user touch on the screen.

Is it possible to turn that off? or if not, what could I use to indicate the changement of status by something similar?

fragment.xml

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/card6"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="5dp"> 

            <TextView     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
                android:text="@string/card6"/>    

            <Switch      
                android:id="@+id/card6_switch"        
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this is the switch I've added. Regardless the thread who will manipulate it, I just hope to disable the touch event of user.

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried?

Comment: If you could be a bit more vague...ok, skip the irony. First rule of asking a question is be specific and provide complete information. What you provided in your question above is vague at its best. Provide the information what you intend to do, and sources that give a good insight in what you tried so far. Then we can help.

Comment: yourSwitch.isEnabled(false) is what you need!

Comment: Actually isEnabled(false) has the side-effect of shadowing the element, or "graying it out", which actually degrades the readability. The solution the OP found himself by setting the attribute clickable="false" is a far better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried some resolution and found one that worked.

for every switch, add

```
android:clickable="false"
```

will do what I've asked.